# Optimize point coordinates of overdetermined triangle strip from measured distances

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, triangles

Suppose we have a triangle strip like in this image (but ignore E and F for the moment, should hopefully not make a difference to add more point later)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIK6m.png]

and we have measured all the distances between every point pair out of `A, B, C and D`. The measurement will not be 100% accurate.

given: approximate distances $AB$, $AC$, $AD$, $BC$, $BD$, $CD$,

How can we compute the point coordinates of A, B, C and D so that the error (e.g. euclidean metric or anything that is appropriate for common sense) between measured distances and found point position distances is minimized?

I think we can choose and fix `A` arbitrarily to be [0,0,0].
What about the other points? Which kind of optimization technique is usable here?

Comment: Do you know the approximate length of $AD$ or just $AB,AC,BC,BD,CD$? If the latter, then this is not overdetermined

Comment: approximate length of $AD$ was measured, too